# PrettyPhoto on WordPress - Lightbox Position Changes depending on Gallery item postion

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox, prettyphoto

For some reason when I add more thumbs to the gallery, so they go onto a second row, the lightbox begins to appear lower down the screen when you click an image.  How can I ensure the lightbox is always centered?

The problem is the lightbox is so low you can see the whole image and the navigation etc vanishes.

If I only have 5 thumbs it's fine, because it's just one row, but this isn't a viable solution.

Many thanks for any help.

The problem can be seen here:

http://mattchungphoto.com/audi-gallery

Answer (score 1):

It might be late but I had the same problem and solved it by modifying a part of the CSS file like this:

```
div.pp_pic_holder {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    float:left;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```